# Як правильно: кала чи калла?

Tags: власні-назви, іменники, орфографія

На означення вазона, який має білий цвіт, в Інтернеті знайшла 2 варіанти:

> [***Кали*** – посадка й догляд, вирощування в саду і вдома](https://floristics.info/ua/statti/sadivnitstvo/2056-kali-posadka-j-doglyad-viroshchuvannya-v-sadu-i-vdoma.html)
>
> ***[Калла домашня](https://agronomist.in.ua/kimnatni-roslini/kvitkovi-roslini/kalla-domashnya-zantedeskiya-doglyad-u-kimnati.html)*** (зантедескія), догляд у кімнаті

То як же правильно зображувати назву квітки на письмі?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В [Українському правописі](http://www.pravopys.net/sections/89/) знаходимо:

> 1. У загальних назвах іншомовного походження приголосні звичайно не подвоюються:акумуля́ція, баро́ко, беладо́на, белетри́стика, браві́симо, ват (хоч Ватт), грип, гру́па, групе́то, гун (гу́ни), ідилі́чний, інтелектуа́льний, інтерме́цо, колекти́в, комі́сія, кому́на, лібре́то, піані́симо, піцика́то, стака́то, су́ма, фін (фі́ни), форти́симо, шасі́, шофе́р та ін.
>      Тільки в окремих загальних назвах зберігається подвоєння приголосних: анна́ли, бо́нна, бру́тто, ва́нна (ва́нний), мадо́нна, ма́нна (ма́нний), мо́тто, не́тто, па́нна, пе́нні, то́нна, білль, бу́лла, ві́лла, мулла́, ду́рра, мі́рра.

Отже, правильно – **кала**.